# WPF DropShadowEffect in ListBox

Tags: wpf

Basically, I have a listbox  which contains a set of listboxitem (stacked horizontally). On selected listboxitem, there will be dropshadoweffect applied to the border of the listboxitem.

The problem i am having at the moment is the dropshadopeffect on the left hand side is covering (on top of) the left listboxitem. This is fine for me, however the dropshadoweffect on the right hand side of the listboxitem is covered by (below) the right listboxitem.

Is there a way to make them consistent? so that both sides' dropshadoweffect will appear on top of the left and right listboxitems.

Comment: I recommend to attach a screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the selected item you need to set its [Panel.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) attached property to 1. If you're retemplating the ListBoxItem, this can be done in xaml with something like:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType=”ListBoxItem”>
    <Border x:Name=”Root” BorderBrush=”#bdc1a3” BorderThickness=”1” CornerRadius=”5”     Background=”{StaticResource NormalBrush}”>
        <ContentPresenter Content=”{TemplateBinding Content}” ContentTemplate=”{TemplateBinding  ContentTemplate}” HorizontalAlignment=”Center” VerticalAlignment=”Center” />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property=”IsSelected” Value=”True”>
            <Setter Property=”Panel.ZIndex” Value=”1” />
            <Setter Property=”BorderBrush” Value=”#2a849d” TargetName=”Root” />
            <Setter Property=”Background” Value=”{StaticResource SelectedBrush}” TargetName=”Root” />
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```